# Fastest way to solve these kinds of fractions (equal to zero and have two variables)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve this:

$$0=\frac{4x-2y}{-5x+y}$$

I can't use partial fractions since there are two variables...

Also, given that there are 2 unknowns and only one equation then I assume one of the variables is "free" and the other is "forced" to be a solution constrained to whatever the free variable is.

What's the fastest way to solve this without inspection or trial-by-error and is it possible to get a solution in terms of $x$ and $y$ only?

EDIT: Too stupid to realize the obvious. As **Git Gud** hinted, this fraction is only equal to zero if the numerator is zero (and the denominator is non-zero). Therefore, this can be completed by solving for the numerator alone:

$$4x-2y=0$$

$$4x=2y$$

$$2x=y$$

Comment: In this particular case it's a simple consequence of the fact that a fraction equals zero if, and only if, what?

Comment: The numerator is equal to zero?

Comment: You should also exclude the points where your fraction isn't well defined, those points satisfy which equation ?

Comment: Ohhhh. Since for this case, the fraction would only equal to zero if the numerator is equal to zero, then just solve for: $numerator = 0$

Comment: Could you elaborate what you guys mean by **"exclude the points where your fraction isn't well defined, those points satisfy which equation?"** ?

Comment: A fraction must have a nonzero denominator.

Comment: A quotient of real numbers (or complex numbers) is equal to $0$ if and only if the numerator is $0$ and the denominator is nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer to this problem is that the solution set is
$$
\{ (x, 2x) :  x \ne 0 \}
$$
i.e., all pairs of the form $(x, 2x)$ where $x$ is any real number except $0$.

What's wrong with $(0, 0)$? Plug it into your original equation, and you get
$$
0 = \frac{4x - 2y}{-5x + y} = \frac{4\cdot 0 - 2\cdot 0}{-5\cdot 0 + 1\cdot 0} = \frac{0}{0}.
$$
But the fraction $0/0$ does *not* equal zero -- it's in fact undefined. So the pair $(0,0)$ does not satisfy the original equation, but all other $(x, 2x)$ pairs do.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should remember to state, for what values of the variable, the equation is undefined for.