# Conditions for regarding only the numerator if a fraction equals zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This is closely related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024194/fastest-way-to-solve-these-kinds-of-fractions-equal-to-zero-and-have-two-variab), see also the [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362641/conditions-for-regarding-only-the-numerator-if-a-fraction-of-generic-functions-e).

Usually we say that if we want to find solutions to $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, it is enough to check where $f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) \neq 0$.

However, consider for example

$$\frac{x^2}{1 + \frac{1}{1-x}} = 0.$$

The numerator gives us the solution $x = 0$ only, but rewriting as

$$\frac{x^2 - x^3}{2 - x}=0$$

reveals that $x = 1$ is a solution as well.

Alternatively, we could think about the denominator going to infinity and therefore the whole term to $0$:

$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{x^2}{1 + \frac{1}{1-x}} = 0.$$

What are the conditions for considering the numerator only?

Comment: $x=1$ is *not* a solution to the equation $$\frac{x^2}{1+\frac{1}{1-x}}.$$  When $x=1$, the denominator is not defined.  The fact that the expression on the left-hand side defines a function which can be continuously extended to a domain containing $1$ does not imply that the equation is solved by $x=1$.

Comment: "but rewriting as ".  You *CAN'T* rewrite $\frac {x^2}{1 + \frac 1{1-x}}$ as $\frac {x^2 - x^3}{2-x}$ unless $x \ne 1$.  As $x=1$ makes $\frac {x^2}{1 + \frac 1{1-x}}$  undefined,  $x=1$ can not be a solution and $\frac {x^2}{1 + \frac 1{1-x}}$ and $\frac {x^2 - x^3}{2-x}$ are not the same thing.

Comment: "What are the conditions for considering the numerator only?"  Like you said in the beginning.  If $f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) \ne 0$.  That doesn't fail you as $x =1$ is *not* a solution.  But you should also have and $g(x)$ is defined.  $\frac {(x-1)^2}{1-\frac 1{1-x}}$ has $f(x) =$ and $g(x)\ne 0$ at $x=1$ but because $g(x)$ is undefined at $x =1$ that is not a solution. If we "rewrote" as $\frac {-(x-1)^3}{x}$ that would not be a legitimate "rewriting". As the first is not definte at $x=1$.

Comment: Yes thank you both, I agree. In this constructed cases with actual functions plugged in, we can't rewrite the equations.
Therefore I regard this question as answered. Since I actually was interested in a general solution, I take the freedom to point you at [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362641/conditions-for-regarding-only-the-numerator-if-a-fraction-of-generic-functions-e].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions must belong to the domain of the function. $x=1$ does not.

You may not freely rewrite. For example, $\dfrac{x^2}x$ has no root, nor $\dfrac1{\frac1x}$.

The complete condition is $$x\in\text{dom}(f)\land x\in\text{dom}(g)\land g(x)\ne0\land f(x)=0.$$

Comment: I mark this as the correct answer, since it concisely shows the conditions, although the others are valid as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can't be answered with a rule about "when to consider only the numerator ..."

The expression

$$ \frac{x^2}{1 + \frac{1}{1-x}} 
$$

is not defined when $x=1$ or $x=2$, so it has no value at those points. The expression

$$
\frac{x^2 - x^3}{2 - x}
$$

is not defined when $x = 2$.

The two expressions agree where they are both defined.

You can only look for values of $x$ that yield $0$ at places where an expression makes sense. That's $x=0$ for the first expression and $x=0,1$ for the second.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was taught is that $x = 1$ is *not* a solution to

$$
\frac{x^2}{1 + \frac{1}{1-x^2}} = 0.
$$

At some point in your factoring, you must have implicitly used the fact that $1 + \frac{1}{1 - x^2} \neq 0$. Even though $x=1$ looks like a solution, it isn't, because you had to divide by something that's $0$ when $x=1$.

Following these rules, you may assume that if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, then $f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) \neq 0$, which is the kind of world I want to live in.

Comment: Ok, let me extend the question then. I am reading about a physical derivation (http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/mechanics.pdf page 7)

Comment: Tasnad. I would recommend asking a new question and not "extending" this one. 
This link that you have posted is quite long and it seems likely to me that you can ask a good new question with some references to this link. Often answerers find it frustrating when the original question is not well contained in the original question because it means that you have to update your answer and read all the comments and it can be a headache. Also welcome to MSE!

Comment: Can't edit any more, sorry. Here the new version:
Ok, let me explain the concrete situation I ran into. I am reading about a physical derivation 
which basically boils down to $ \frac{f''}{g(f')} = 0 $ and they simply ignore the denominator. Since the functions are not specifically defined, there is no way to fix the relation between the numerator and denominator.
Here is the source for reference (page 7, top): [http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/mechanics.pdf]
So what if we use a function which behaves like my example?

Comment: Again. I really think you are going to get more out of this site (and contribute more to this community) if you ask this question as a different question where you include the relevant elements to your question in the post.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the good advice, the question is on its way. You were too quick and I am still a little bit overwhelmed by all the restrictions here and how quick people react!

Comment: @Tasnad. Totally fair. Be patient with this community and you may grow to enjoy it. I certainly do. I also had a type of culture shock when I came to Math Stack Exchange. If you enjoy the website learning the culture here is well worth your time.