# Conditions for regarding only the numerator if a fraction of generic functions equals zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Related / extension to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362571/conditions-for-regarding-only-the-numerator-if-a-fraction-equals-zero).

Usually we say that if we want to find solutions to $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, it is enough to check where $f(x) = 0$ while considering that $g(x) \neq 0$ (see also [the referenced question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362571/conditions-for-regarding-only-the-numerator-if-a-fraction-equals-zero)).

I am reading about a physical derivation which basically boils down to 
$$\frac{f''}{g(f')} = 0$$ 
Here is the source for reference (page 7, top): [Malham - "An Introduction to Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics"](https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/mechanics.pdf).

Since the functions are not specifically defined, there is no way to know the relation between numerator and denominator. As a pathological example, consider $f'' = x^2$ and $g(f') = 1 - \frac{1}{1-x}$:
$$\frac{x^2}{1 + \frac{1}{1-x}} = 0$$

The numerator gives us the solution $x = 0$.

As far as I can see, there is no "hidden" connection between denominator and numerator, so we can manipulate the equation into 
$$\frac{x^2 - x^3}{2 - x}=0$$
and we see that $x = 1$ is a solution as well. In [the reference above](https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/mechanics.pdf), they simply ignore the denominator and state that $f'' = 0$ is the only solution.

I have seen this reasoning in many places, so I suppose it is correct, but why can we ignore the denominator?

Comment: I can't find the spot in the reference that you're referring to. Page number $7$, or the $7$th page in the pdf?

Comment: I mean page 7 in the manuscript's numbering, 15th page in the pdf.